# How to Join Two tables in Two differnet Database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server, I have a Table A in Adb and Table B in Bdb

```
A Have ID={1,2},Name={Scott,Tiger}
and 
B Have ID={1,2,3},Department={Dept1,Dept2,Dept3}
```

I want to join both tables with join, my query is similar like this.

```
SELECT a.ID,a.Name,b.Department FROM Adb.dbo.A as a INNER JOIN Bdb.dbo.B as b
on a.ID=b.ID
```

But my query always return table with null values. how i can solve this?

Answer (score 3):

If it is on the same Server just prefix table name with database name and owner.

```
 [DatabaseName].[Owner].[TableName]
```

Comment: Did you check your cross database permissions?